# Editing grammar and spelling?

Tags: discussion, editing

I'm new, so I'm not 100% sure this is the right place to ask this. But I'm pretty sure... >_>

I've come across a few posts (on photo and security SE sites) that have poor grammar/spelling/phrasing of questions. I usually put it down to English being a second language rather than laziness, but I'm frequently tempted to edit the posts to correct things.
Is there a general rule around this? I trialled an edit earlier today, and it seemed to be fine with the moderators. 
Obviously it wouldn't be reasonable to re-format the entire question, but some just to clear things up from time to time. I assume it would have to be within reason, I'm just wondering what the community 'thoughts' are around it.

Comment: That is absolutely what edits are for. They recommend not editing for a very minor single edit, but otherwise as long as you keep the spirit of the original post, edit away!

Comment: If the question is one long breathless paragraph, I'm all for re-formatting the entire thing.

Comment: Also, while you're at it, see if the title can be improved and add any tags that seem relevant.

Comment: Great! I'll do so as i see useful then. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad you asked.  I have rejected edits where someone did nothing but change flickr to Flickr, but then I catch myself making similar trivial edits.  One thing to be careful of is making fairly trivial edits to old questions, as that bumps them to the front page.

Comment: I love that my post just got edited! ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a general rule around this?

The general rule is that if you can improve a question or answer without changing the author's intent, you should feel free to do so. See [Other people can edit my posts?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#editing) in the [faq]. It's the same rule on [all StackExchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites), by the way.

> Obviously it wouldn't be reasonable to re-format the entire question
>   but some just to clear things up from time to time.

If reformatting the entire question makes it a better question, then do it. Again, respect the author's intent. But if someone posts a list of f/stops (or whatever) in a paragraph and you're pretty sure you can make it more readable by formatting it as a list, go ahead. Editing for spelling and/or grammar are fine. On the other hand, don't be too picky -- there's no need to edit a question to fix a single little typo where the meaning isn't in question.